# Cloudfoundry : Activate some PHP extentions in a custom buildpack

Tags: cloud-foundry

I want to enlable some PHP extentions in my custom PHP-Buildpack. But I don't know which one to edit... I tried to change the options.json in the "defaults" folder, but I get an error when I push the app via the cf command. And there is easily 20 other files named like that.

Can somebody help me to find the good one ? Thank you :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. As is,  your question is going to be tough for someone to help you. You don't mention the error seen, nor provide details of the files giving you confusion, nor is it clear what command you are running (just 'cf' or maybe there are arguments). It might be worth editing your question to clarify, and reviewing https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Tim Hi, thanks for your advices. After a hour of tests, I finally find how to do it. 
For the others : The file has to be on the app folder, not the buildpack folder.

Comment: Great. Here on SO you can answer your own question, help people searching for answers on the same subject

Answer (score 0):

The file has to be on the app folder, not in the buildpack folder. It has to be in a folder named ".bp-config" on the root of your app's directory.